# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::searchable()

Tags: php, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

I am trying to import some existing records to algolia. now using `Laravel 5.5` and `scout 3.0.0` with algolia-php-sdk. when I execute `php artisan scout:import "App\Listings" -v`, it throws the following exception

```
 [BadMethodCallException]                                                  
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::searchable()  


Exception trace:
 () at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2457
 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1273
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/scout/src/Searchable.php:102
 App\Listings::makeAllSearchable() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/scout/src/Console/ImportCommand.php:43
 Laravel\Scout\Console\ImportCommand->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:549
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:180
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:262
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:167
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:888
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:224
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:125
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:88
 Illuminate\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:121
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/vagrant/Code/artisan:35
`
```

I have included `Searchable` trait in the model also the `toSearchableArray()` method to customize the record being inserted.

I have another model called `Store`. and I can import that model to algolia without any problem. I have gone through [this link](https://github.com/laravel/scout/issues/179). but both my models are extending the same basemodel class so the above link didn't helped me either.

any hints on going forward would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Code Sample

```
namespace App;

use App\Services\Search\Builders\ListingRecordBuilder;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
.
.
.

class Listings extends BaseModel
{
    use Searchable;
.
.
.
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'local_listings_new';
    }

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $recordBuilder = new ListingRecordBuilder($this);

        return $recordBuilder->buildRecord();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you import the method?

Comment: hi @HaroenViaene I have updated the question with some code that I use and YES, I have imported the trait and used it in the model, and this thing works perfectly with another model also.

Comment: also the `record builder` returns perfect array structure and i have even tried with only one field in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out myself. The model contained an `$indices` array/property which is used to denote the algolia index where the record is being inserted. at the same time, it contains a `searchableAs()` method also which is doing the same task of specifying the algolia index. and that `$indices` array is populated via the constructor, so in the first look I was not able to reveal the culprit.

So simply removing the `$indices` array and the code where the constructor does the initialization of `$indices` did work for me. But still its unknown that why Scout throws `Call to undefined method::Searchable()` Exception